# Adding a switch to an overflow menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

in my application I have just created an overflow menu (the icon with the three points), and I have added three options: Settings, Language and Official Site.

Now I would like to add also a switch, the one with ON-OFF, directly in the overflow.

This is the code I have now:

Main activity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And menu.main xlm

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/language"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Language"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/linktosite"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Official Site"/> </menu>
```

I hope you can help me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow menus do not support custom views, such as a `Switch`. You can, however, make an item checkable by adding `android:checkable="true"` to your `<item>` definition to show a checkbox next to that item (on 3.0+ devices) as explained in the [Using checkable menu items guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable).